# How to protect EF DBContext Connection String from getting stored in process dump file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a windows form application that use **Entity Framework 4 (EF4)** to read and write data from/to SQL Server.
When I create dump file for my application, connection string stored in output dump file clearly.

how can I **protect** connection string from getting stores in **dump file**?

**Create dump file:**

Go to Task Manager -> Go to Process Tab -> Right click on your windows application that use EF(for example MyTest.exe) -> Create dump file

Now open the file in notepad and search **ConnectionString** in file. You see that **runtime connection string** stored in file clearly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't protect it. This is why it's recommended to use Windows auth (not login / password) for SQL server connections. It will not be available in memory, BUT the tradeoff is that information about the windows account will be available in the client config and at the time of connection to the server for the first time.